# What's the etymology of "accounts receivable"?

Tags: terminology

Gill, Madura. [*Personal Finance*, 4th Canadian Edition 2019](https://www.amazon.ca/Personal-Finance-Canadian-Pearson-Package/dp/013485201X/ref=pd_cp_14_1?pd_rd_w=c29n6&pf_rd_p=64a84aa4-b549-4445-9bf3-48bdeed5f24a&pf_rd_r=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41&pd_rd_r=ac94fdf8-0331-4f63-9fd4-08392967896d&pd_rd_wg=LkHyc&pd_rd_i=013485201X&psc=1&refRID=82BZKGBE1YW3BZXRTA41). p 332. Emboldenings are mine.

> Short-term assets include cash, securities purchased by the firm, accounts receivable (money owed to the firm for previous sales), and inventories (materials used to produce products and finished products waiting to be sold).

[accounts receivable | Definition of accounts receivable in English by Lexico Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/accounts_receivable)

> Money owed to a company by its debtors.

1. Am I correct "receivables" is a [post-postpositive adjective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postpositive_adjective#Set_phrases)?
2. Why "receivable"? If a debtor is still alive and solvent, technically any debt is "receivable". Thus "receivable" looks meaningless. "unreceived" is clearer.
3. Why "accounts"? Why not "money" or just "debt"? You, the creditor, want your debtors' money, not their accounts.

En masse, "unreceived money" or "unreceived debt" looks a better term.

Comment: Why do we park on the driveway but drive on the parkway? I think Gerald Weinberg captured it best with *"things are the way they are because they got that way."* Accountants and bookkeepers may have had a different idea about their profession's terminology than the rest of us, valuing precision over simplicity (having potential ambiguity).

Comment: There are no emboldenings (that I can see).

Comment: In English it should be "receivable accounts" and "payable accounts", but perhaps it came from another language with a different word order, or perhaps it's so they come next to each other when sorted alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

Companies keep track of multiple types of accounts in their relations with other entities.

Companies keep accounts for all of their vendors that they buy supplies and services from. These accounts are the amounts that the company owes to their vendors. They are called *accounts payable*, because the company must eventually pay these amounts.

Likewise, companies keep accounts for all of their customers, and the amounts in these accounts represent money that is owed to the company. These accounts are called *accounts receivable*, because the company expects to receive the money in these accounts.

The term “receivable” is not meant to differentiate these accounts from those where the debtor will not pay, as you suggest in your question. Instead, it is used to differentiate the accounts from those accounts where the company owes money to other entities, which are “payable” accounts.

Answer (score 1):

> Why "receivable"? If a debtor is still alive and solvent, technically any debt is "receivable". Thus "receivable" looks meaningless. "unreceived" is clearer.

You are right, all debts that are reasonably expected to be collected are receivable.  Charged off or noncollectable debts go somewhere else in the accounting.

> Why "accounts"? Why not "money" or just "debt"? You, the creditor, want your debtors' money, not their accounts.

The debtor has an account with you on your books in your accounting.

So the account containing the debt is receivable.